# Getting npm: command not found in running docker containter

Tags: docker, automation, dockerfile, playwright

I am getting an error below when running the docker container

> 2024-02-01 14:23:28 ./src/portal/run_tests.sh: line 6: npm: command not found
> 2024-02-01 14:23:28 ./src/portal/run_tests.sh: line 9: npx: command not found
> 2024-02-01 14:23:28 ./src/portal/run_tests.sh: line 12: npm: command not found

This the content of my shell script: run_tests.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

#whatever commands you need to run to execute tests for feature branch

#Install dependencies
npm ci

#Install Playwright Browsers
npx playwright install --with-deps

#Run Portal tests on Dev environment
npm run env:dev
```

This is the content of my Docker file

```
FROM docker/whalesay:latest

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | bash
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT [ "./src/portal/run_tests.sh" ]
```

This is the steps I ran:

```bash
docker build . --file Dockerfile -t qe-portal-tests
docker run -t -d --name qe-portal-tests-container qe-portal-tests /bin/bash
```

After running the second line, I am getting the error I posted above in the logs in Docker dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are using the `docker/whalesay` image: I'm replacing that with the `node` image. Try this.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN chmod u+x /app/src/portal/run_tests.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "./src/portal/run_tests.sh" ]
```

`run_tests.sh` (which resides in `./src/portal/`)

```
#!/bin/bash

npm ci

npm install playwright --with-deps

npm run env:dev
```